# How do I restart a Windows service from a script?

Tags: windows-service, windows-command-prompt

I have a batch script that looks like:

```
sc stop myservice
sc start myservice
```

it errors out because sc doesn't wait till the service is stopped. How do I restart a service with a script?

Comment: what about [this](http://www.codeplex.com/restarts)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The poster wants to ensure the service is stopped before trying to restart it.  You can use a loop on the output of "sc query" doing something like this:

```
:stop
sc stop myservice

rem cause a ~10 second sleep before checking the service state
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 -w 1000 > nul

sc query myservice | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
if errorlevel 1 goto :stop
goto :start

:start
net start | find /i "My Service">nul && goto :start
sc start myservice
```

Comment: Nice use of ping as a time delay.

Comment: Thanks, there's no sleep in batch so that's all you can do to wait :)

Comment: +1, and a GOTO badge. Awarded to those that use a GOTO statement with a straight face.

Comment: If only batch supported do/while loops... It's trivial in C#, really!

Comment: I'd change the `sc query myservice | find "STOPPED"` to `sc query myservice| find /I "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED"' to make sure you're getting the STATE line.

Comment: @crb +1 We use almost identical code as part of install script. There is a `sleep` for Windows though, from the Resource Kit.  http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html

Comment: If you're prepared to install the Resource Kit, you could install PowerShell. :)

Comment: I believe FIND returns 0 if the string was found. Shouldn't you be testing for 0 instead of 1 in this case?

Comment: @Lars: correct, but if we don't find "stopped", we loop back to stop (the next goto) - if do find "stopped" then it's time to start it!

Comment: So if it's stopped, sc query myservice | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED" returns 0, the if errorlevel 1 returns false and you go to :stop to stop it again? I must be missing something here.

Comment: In Windows Server 2008, the error level is **0** when found and **1** when not found.  So I had to invert the logic and then it worked.

Answer (score 31):

May be missing something, but I use this all the time:

> net stop "myservice" 
>   net start "myservice"

or shorter:

> net stop "myservice" && net start "myservice"

Answer (score 25):

Dead simple with powershell:

```
PS >Restart-Service MySrvcHere
```

Even better, using display names:

```
PS >Restart-Service -displayname "My Service Name Here"
```

`Get-Help Restart-Service` for more

Answer (score 6):

If it is purely for restarting the service, you can use

```
Net stop myservice
Net start myservice
```

However, if you want access to the options of sc, you can use the start /wait command

```
start /B /WAIT CMD /C "sc stop myservice"
start /B /WAIT CMD /C "sc start myservice"
```

this technique is a more general solution that can be applied to any command.

Comment: `sc stop myservice` will just send the stop command and return before the service is stopped. Calling sc with start /b won't help.

Answer (score 5):

To have **quiet** restart of some service, which asks confirmations to be stopped (as Server service, for example), You could add **/y** to the end of stop command.

```
net stop Server /y
net start Server
```

It would be helpful for automatic script execution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restart a failed service you do not need to run a script.  In the services MMC snapin right click on a service, select properties, click the recovery tab.  Here you can set what actions you want taken should the service stop.  There is alot of flexibility available.  You will need a script if y ou are trying to stop the service , do something then start the script, preface the batch file with `net stop "myserviceshortname"` and end with `net start "myserviceshortname"`

In vbscipt it's a little more code to stop a service and its' dependants:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Associators of " _
   & "{Win32_Service.Name='myservice'} Where " _
        & "AssocClass=Win32_DependentService " & "Role=Antecedent" )
For each objService in colServiceList
    objService.StopService()
Next
Wscript.Sleep 20000
Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Service where Name='myservice'")
For each objService in colServiceList
    errReturn = objService.StopService()
Next
```

Here's starting a service and anything it depends on (this should be familiar)

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Service where Name='Myservice'")
For each objService in colServiceList
    errReturn = objService.StartService()
Next
Wscript.Sleep 20000
Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Associators of " _
   & "{Win32_Service.Name='myservice'} Where " _
        & "AssocClass=Win32_DependentService " & "Role=Dependent" )
For each objService in colServiceList
    objService.StartService()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following commands:

```
@echo off
sc Stop <Name of Agentry Service Here>
timeout 30
sc start <Name of Agentry Service Here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a hybrid: in *.cmd file:

```
powershell -Command "& {Restart-Service MyService;}"
```